# how to send post request with data in Volley?

Tags: android, android-networking, android-volley

This is my android code

```
           JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
           params.put("username","rajesh@gmail.com");
           params.put("password","hellothere");

           JsonObjectRequest loginRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                    Request.Method.POST,
                    "http://192.168.2.67/tmp/test.php",
                    params,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                        Log.d("","");

                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        Log.d("","");
                        }
                    });


            requestQueue.add(loginRequest);
```

The server code in php

```
            <?php
               $usr = $_REQUEST['username'];
                $pwd = $_REQUEST['password'];
                $resp[$usr]=$pwd;
                echo json_encode($resp);
               ?>
```

the response i'm getting is
{"":null}

I tried with apache http cleint and it worked prferectly
is there any way i can do this with volley?

Comment: Please see this answer:


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837820/volley-jsonobjectrequest-post-request-not-working/19945676#19945676

Answer (score 6):

> To send parameters in request body you need to override either
>   **getParams()** or **getBody()** method of the request classes

Source: [Asynchronous HTTP Requests in Android Using Volley](http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/)

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() 
{  
Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();  
    params.put("username", "SomeUser");  
    params.put("password", "blabla");



 return params;  
}
```

This is the way you should override getParams() method.

Comment: Are you sure my friend? I have been using this approach for lots and lots of POST requests. It works fine.

Comment: Do you return JSONOrject or a String? I use CustomVolleyRequest posted by someone in stackoverflow. It works fine

Comment: it's the other way around, it's called on POST requests but not on GET requests.

Comment: where is this custom volley request? @BalaVishnu

Comment: StringRequest lets u specify whether post or get. It is under Volley toolbox